# ctags is not working for polymorphic function

Tags: c++, c++11, vim, ctags

I am using ctags command line tool to navigate the c++ code but when I wanted to jump to polymorphic function definition, it won't jump properly to that definition. Please tell if there is some problem with ctags or some other configurations to be added. Or please let me know if there is better tool to navigate modern C++ code. Thank you!

I usually run ctags command as follows(on VIM):

> ctags -R *

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to navigate C++ code, I guess you are using Exuberant Ctags.

[This Exuberant Ctags Mailinglist response](https://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/mailman/message/21849873/) explains how to jump to definitions of virtual functions:

> if you look at the tags file, you should see all declarations &
>   definitions of my_func are present. if not, and the declaration is
>   missing, try adding --c++-kinds=+p to the command line of whatever's
>   generating your tags file.

You can look at all the possible c++-kinds using `ctags --list-kinds=c++`:

```
c  classes
d  macro definitions
e  enumerators (values inside an enumeration)
f  function definitions
g  enumeration names
l  local variables [off]
m  class, struct, and union members
n  namespaces
p  function prototypes [off]
s  structure names
t  typedefs
u  union names
v  variable definitions
x  external and forward variable declarations [off]
```

---

About your second question, whether there is a better tool to navigate modern C++ code: [Many IDEs do use ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags). But I am currently using [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/specials/clion/clion.html?gclid=CjwKCAiA4ILSBRA0EiwAsuuBLc-OPLyJFT5VZOtIHJCKPdjH3EdyH0WqG5IvG8j0Zz_6oNqIQUQIPRoCn3QQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds.ds&dclid=CMX0t8XrpNgCFUaMdwodsCUB2w), which offers [some good search and navigation features](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/03/search-and-navigation-in-clion/). You also get an overview of these cheat sheets:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/features/navigation-and-usages-searches.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/navigation-in-source-code.html

However, sometimes navigation does not work, e.g. `find usage` for ctors. Furthermore, my Clion has quite some performance issues. Maybe, you want to try out instead:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/download
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator